# нее могу получить родительский элемент jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть разметка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть обработчик событий на нажатие "span class='close'"

```
    $("docement").ready(function () {

    $(".close").on("click",function (e) {
var el = $(this).parent().children(".kek");

console.log(el.val()); *вывод тут*
});
        });
 и тут мне выводит пустое место, я пытался даже использовать .show() / .hide, но значение все равно пустое. А если я использую классическое .value, то выводит вообще undefined! Что делать?
```

Comment: `console.log(el.parentNode);` или `console.log($(el).parent());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```js
$("span").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo foo_1"><span>Click me</span></div>
<div class="foo foo_2"><span>Click me</span></div>
<div class="foo foo_3"><span>Click me</span></div>
```

**Vanilla JS**

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".foo > span")].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="foo foo_1"><span>Click me</span></div>
<div class="foo foo_2"><span>Click me</span></div>
<div class="foo foo_3"><span>Click me</span></div>
```

Comment: спасибо держи галку))

Answer (score 0):

[`e.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) возвращает `HTMLElement`.

У элементов нет свойства `parent`, есть свойства [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) и [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

Так как уже используется `jQuery` можно воспользоваться методом [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)